# Hadoop MultipleOutPutFormat and Join Query

Tags: hadoop

I am working on a hadoop task which was earlier populating few files in a directory say

part-o
part-1
part-2

I modified this task because of a requirement and used MultipleOutputs to capture few more outputs. so now directory structures looks like

part-0
part-1
part-2
output-1
output-2
output-3

Issue : earlier few jobs were using this directory for a map side outer join but now the job has to take only part-* files for join and discard rest of the files.

i tried giving the input as a ","  separated directories
i.e */part-1,*/part-2,*/part-3

and as per the following expression
jobConf.set("mapred.join.expr", CompositeInputFormat.compose(outer,
                KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, path[]))

now my path[] contains 5 entires which ealier used to be 3, in a way the starting three indexes have */part-1,*/part-2,*/part-3 paths and rest two as it were earlier.

I am not sure if i am doing this right way, please suggest me what should i do so that this join works as it used to work earlier without output-* files.

it is throwing following exception with the above approach.

java.io.IOException: Inconsistent split cardinality from child 1 (12/6)
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.join.Parser$CNode.getSplits(Parser.java:369)
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.join.CompositeInputFormat.getSplits(CompositeInputFormat.java:117)
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)

JobConf Values are the following.

```
 jobConf.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    jobConf.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

  String[] foldersToJoin = StringUtils.split(getInputString(), Constants.COMMA);
    Path[] pathsToJoin =  new Path[foldersToJoin.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(String folder : foldersToJoin){
        pathsToJoin[i++] = new Path(folder);
    }

 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, new Path("/MyOutPUT"));

    jobConf.setInputFormat(CompositeInputFormat.class);
    jobConf.set("mapred.join.expr", CompositeInputFormat.compose(Constants.OUTER_JOIN_OP,
            KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, pathsToJoin));

    jobConf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    jobConf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    jobConf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(jobConf, CHANGE_SET_A,
            TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(jobConf, CHANGE_SET_B,
            TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(jobConf,CHANGE_SET_C,
            TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(jobConf, CHANGE_SET_D,
            TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
```

i am appending all the files in the folder as a "," separated string following is the code to it

```
  mapred.join.expr = CompositeInputFormat.compose(Constants.OUTER_JOIN_OP,
        KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, pathsToJoin)

   where pathsToJoin =  new Path[]{new Path["/home/hadoop/folder1/part-1"],
  new Path["/home/hadoop/folder1/part-2"],new Path["/home/hadoop/folder1/part-3"],
   new Path["/home/hadoop/folder2"],new Path["/home/hadoop/folder3"] }
```

so basically i am trying to join only part-* files present in folder1 with folder2 and folder3

Any doc, or any link to this kind of scenario would be of great help.

Comment: can you post your driver code (where you're calling JobConf.setXXX methods). I suspect you just need to craft a better glob when defining your input files for the CombineInputFormat)

Comment: added the jobConf code in question.

Comment: Where are you setting the values of the `pathsToJoin` array?

Comment: Can you show the resolved job configuration property `"mapred.join.expr"` as well - thanks!

Comment: mapred.join.expr = CompositeInputFormat.compose(Constants.OUTER_JOIN_OP,
        KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, pathsToJoin)

   where pathsToJoin =  new Path[]{new Path["/home/hadoop/folder1/part-1"],
  new Path["/home/hadoop/folder1/part-2"],new Path["/home/hadoop/folder1/part-3"],
   new Path["/home/hadoop/folder2"],new Path["/home/hadoop/folder3"] }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i think i understand this now.

You have executed a number of jobs which have output their contents to a folder:

```
job1 -> folder1
job2 -> folder2
job3 -> folder3
```

Now you want to use the CompositeInputFormat to merge output from each part-r-x in each folder and process in a single mapper

```
map0 - merged contents of folder1/part-r-0, folder2/part-r-0, folder3/part-r-0
map1 - merged contents of folder1/part-r-1, folder2/part-r-1, folder3/part-r-1
.. and so on ..
```

The added complexity you have is one or more of the jobs was using MultipleOutputs, so rather than part-r-x files in folder1, you have

```
job1 -> folder1/part-x and folder1/output-x
```

And when you come to use the `CompositeInputFormat`, it's erroring because folder1 has more files than folder2 and 3

In this case i think you need to amend the `mapred.join.expr` value to use some globs:

```
// use glob for folder1, to only include the part-x files (ignoring the output-x files)
CompositeInputFormat.compose(Constants.OUTER_JOIN_OP, KeyValueTextInputFormat.class,
   new Path[] {
       new Path('folder1/part-*'),
       new Path('folder2/part-r-*'),
       new Path('folder3/part-r-*'),
   });
```

Comment: Assuming that you've already gone through "Hadoop the definitive guide" by Tom White, what else would you like to get a hold on? As with most things you've got to experiment, and learn from your mistakes